# MOSFET for switching 1000 W ZVS induction heater?

Tags: mosfet, induction, heater, zvs

I have a 48V power supply powering a 1000 W ZVS induction heater. I would like to switch the heater on and off with an Arduino. Is using a logic level MOSFET appropriate for this?

Comment: does the power supply have a control signal

Comment: MSB - Now that you have removed the "recommendations request" (i.e. shopping) part of the question, which was the reason given for its closure, I will re-open it for the community to have another look.

Comment: yeah, that can work. it might require a little shopping around, and i would suggest using a logic level converter to feed the fet 12v to ensure minimal Rds(on).

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn’t suggest using a n chan mosfet to switch the low side of the induction heater circuit. All you need is a sneek path back to 0V and the heater will start working - at the worst possible time.

The obvious solution is to get a relay board to switch the 48V. You might need the relay to switch a larger relay due to the high current required by the induction heater. Relays are pretty simple and robust, so much harder to make a mistake using them.

A higher-tech approach is the use a logic level mosfet and have it disable the operation of the heater electronics. This requires knowledge of the circuit, thus not a suggested solution if you are not experienced with such things.